# MYSQL view not filling up empty spots to fill 1000

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query gets the popular questions from the questions asked in the last 2 days. It looks at a feed table to see whats talked about latest, then it searches a tag table to find which one of those is popular.

I only get about 60 results which is great, but I need 1000 results. This means I need to fill up the rest with random questions.

My sql query attempts to do this but does not fill in the rest of the view with more questions not in the feed table.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `popular` AS
    select 
        `q`.`name` AS `name`,
        `q`.`questionUrl` AS `questionUrl`,
        `q`.`miRating` AS `miRating`,
        `q`.`imageUrl` AS `imageUrl`,
        `q`.`foundOn` AS `foundOn`,
        `q`.`myId` AS `myId`
    from
        (`question` `q`
        join `feed` `f` ON ((`q`.`myId` = `f`.`question_id`))

        join `tag` `t` ON ((`q`.`myId` = `t`.`question_id`)))

    where
        (`t`.`name` like '%popular%')
    group by `q`.`name`
    order by (max(`f`.`timeStamp`) >= (now() - interval 1 day)) desc , (`q`.`myId` is not null) desc
    limit 0 , 1000comment
```

Comment: You can search for `2-day` and `other` questions separately, then `UNION` the results and `limit` the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need random questions, remove the `where` clause and move the logic to the `order by`:

```
select 
    `q`.`name` AS `name`,
    `q`.`questionUrl` AS `questionUrl`,
    `q`.`miRating` AS `miRating`,
    `q`.`imageUrl` AS `imageUrl`,
    `q`.`foundOn` AS `foundOn`,
    `q`.`myId` AS `myId`
from
    (`question` `q`
    join `feed` `f` ON ((`q`.`myId` = `f`.`question_id`))
    join `tag` `t` ON ((`q`.`myId` = `t`.`question_id`)))
group by `q`.`name`
order by (max(`f`.`timeStamp`) >= (now() - interval 1 day)) desc ,
         max(`t`.`name` like '%popular%') desc,
         rand()
limit 0 , 1000;
```

Comment: Ok, doesnt this get random for all 1000? I just need random after the initial 60 come back (because with the code in my question the view only has 60 questions, so after that i want to add an additional 940 random questions

Comment: @waf - 
As I already said, have **two** similar queries fetching 1,000 records each. One for 2-day, another for random. Make additional column that will be (let say) `1` for 2-day and `0` for random.  UNION the two queries.  Put `LIMIT 1000` on the result with `ORDER BY` starting with this new field, so your 2-day records take precedence.